# Python Web Scraping returns strange characters

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use Python to retrieve some text from a website and then create a *.txt* file with that text.
I'm using Beautiful Soup 4 and Requests to get the info from the site. I am able to pull the text and create the file, no problems, but when I open the generated text on VSCode I get this:

```
�It�s the year 3486 of the Saint Origin calendar. I was dead for over a hundred years. Jiang Chen, my name is�Jiang Chen. Why have I been reborn after a hundred years?�
```

Comparing this to the website, we can see that � is supposed to be a certain punctuation. I then tried using:

```py
text = text.replace(u"\u201c", '"')
```

To replace some of the double quotes, but that only solves part of the problem, it leaves a lot of � left around and trying to find all the punctuation to use the same method is not feasible.

Is there a way to fix this, maybe forcing the type of characters I want to use?

Here is my source code if needed:

```py
# MODULES NEEDED:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Link from which we want the text:
link =  "http://liberspark.com/read/dragon-marked-war-god/chapter-1"

# Getting the page's source code:
source = requests.get(link)

# Creating the BeautifulSoup object:
source = BeautifulSoup(source.content.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")

# Finding the the div which holds the text:
container = source.find("div", class_="reader-content")

# Variable that will hold all the text:
text =  ""

# Going through all the <p> tags in the container:
for p in container.find_all("p"):
    text +=  str(p.text) +  "\n\n"

text = text.replace(u"\u2019", "'")

with  open("test.txt", "w") as  file:
    file.write(text)
```

Comment: The page might not actually be UTF-8 encoded; check the HTML (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta charset attribute, perhaps) and/or some of the response headers of your request (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type charset).

Comment: And since you're using `requests`, you might be better off using `response.text` instead of `response.content.decode('utf-8')`, as `requests` will do a better job of checking those things for you than you manually having to check for all the weird edge cases that the Internet presents.

Comment: Looked through the site's source code but could not find any `<meta>` tags that specified the encoding. Changing `source.content.decode("utf-8")` to `source.text` didn't do it as well, I guess it must be some font I have not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `test.txt` not written in `utf-8` format, write the file using binary mode by using `wb` flag and `.encode('utf-8')`

```
with open("test.txt", "wb") as  file:
    file.write(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Right! This worked, thank you! I tried using `text.encode("utf-8")` before but it didn't work but opening the file as `"wb"` solved it!